# Illustrator: I have paragraph styles with baseline shifts, can I make a character style to add to that shift?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, paragraph-styles, character-styles

This is kind of a confusing question, so let me try and elaborate. I made paragraph styles with different baseline shifts depending where they start around objects. For example directly to the left is -6, but 45° diagonally to the left and below is -13 and directly above is 8 and so on.

Now I have a character style to grab a bracket and change it to a font that has a glyph. This wasn't a problem until the client wanted the glyph to be smaller. The glyph was built so the interior symbol matches the x height of regular fonts and then has a background that matches the descender and goes symmetrically above the cap height.

Now for the question: The client wants the glyph smaller so the background matches the x height, but only on this project so adjusting the font wouldn't make sense. So can I make a character style that would essentially take (paragraph style baseline shift + 1) so that no matter what paragraph styles baseline shift it gets paired with it stays appropriately shifted?

Or am I going to have to make as many character styles for this glyph as there are paragraph styles?

Comment: I think you'd need to try this to find out. It's very specific. AI paragraph/character styles often work in reverse compared to the logic of other styles such as InDesign and Photoshop.

Comment: I think there might be a way to do it with the Adobe Illustrator scripting with like Javascript. So far its looking like I can't type in <var PStyle = paragraph style "x" baseline shift, function sum(input){ "PStyle" + 3} then return the value for the baseline shift.

It will probably just be faster to make 8 character styles to match the 8 paragraph styles.